# Rename character vector in pipeline

Tags: r, pipe

Can I connect the following two codes into one with the pipeline?

```
v <- c(1:3)
names(v) <- letters[1:3]
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
v <- c(1:3) %>% rename_with(~ letters[1:3])
```

Of course it doesn't work; it says:

> "Error in UseMethod("rename_with") : no applicable method for 'rename_with' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

The reason I want to do this is that I need to construct an object like `v` above using the `targets` package.

Comment: If you wanna stick with `tidyverse`, you can do:  `1:3 %>% set_names(letters[1:3])`.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it with `setNames()`:

```r
v <- 1:3 |> setNames(letters[1:3])
v
#> a b c 
#> 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `setNames()` like @LiangZhang's answer. Here I provide another point of view for this issue.

---

This line `names(v) <- letters[1:3]` is actually evaluated as follows:

```r
`names<-`(v, letters[1:3])
```

You can regard `` `names<-` `` as a function and adapt it for a pipeline:

```r
v |> `names<-`(letters[1:3])

# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```

Also, `names(v) <- letters[1:3]` is equivalent to add an attribute called ***"names"*** to the vector `v`, i.e.

```r
attr(v, "names") <- letters[1:3]
```

Hence, the pipeline can be also written as

```r
v |> `attr<-`("names", letters[1:3])

# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```